# maven publish artifacts to local repository fail

Tags: maven, gradle

I would like to test my publish task locally first before deploy it to maven server. I wish it can be deploy to local maven repository as below but it doesn't work

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'release'
            url "/home/user/.m2/repository"
            credentials {
                username = ""
                password = ""
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        deployApp(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "com.sample"
            artifactId "demo"
            version "1.0.0"
            artifact ("demo.apk")
        }
    }
}
```

What's the proper way to verify publish task locally?

Answer (score 1):

to locally publish you just need

```
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      artifact bootJar //replace with your artefact
    }
  }
}
```

it defaults to `/Users/username/.m2/repository`

remove your repositories section